# Constraint the EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to do the following thing: be not able to resize the EditText widget. Because when I enter a long string, all my layout structure is crashing down, because the EditText occupies the whole screen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use singleLine and Layoutwidth(with fix size) property together.
See this:

```
<EditText 
    android:text="ok" 
    android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
    android:layout_width="300dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    ></EditText>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly define Scroll then Layout and then EditText. Like This

```
<?xml>
<ScrollView>
<LinerLayout>
<EditText/>
<LinerLayout/>
</ScrollView>
```

I hope you will find solution.

Answer (score 1):

make the EditText to be in a single Line.. here is  an example.

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/InscripChampNom"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:textSize="14px"
           android:inputType="textPersonName" 
           android:layout_marginRight="20dip"

           android:singleLine="true" ---->HERE

           android:textColor="@color/background">

  </EditText>
```

Comment: I tried the "singleLine", and it works just fine in case I don't use the virtual keybord. If I do have it, it becomes a total mess.

Comment: whats problem with virtual keyboard? how it can make a mess? can u give some snapshots.

Comment: Sorry, me bad. It does not. But if I use the "singleLine" alone, the EditText get stretched in width, so I guess I have to use the "singleLine" + sth like "layout_width="40dp". For me it's not the best solution, as I though the Android have something like "android:constraint="true" and that's all, but it seems it doesn't. Though, I will play with ScrollView as well.